# Text matching of company names

Tags: text, match

I have company names like :

1.Apple Inc.
2.Apple computers Inc.
3.Apple
4.IBM
5.International business machines
4.international business machines corporation
5.International business machines corp
6.Ibm corp..

I need to match the text with correct company name and replace all the other similars with correct company name ...is there any way ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a [python library](https://github.com/seatgeek/fuzzywuzzy) that do the name matching.

```
> choices = ["Atlanta Falcons", "New York Jets", "New York Giants", "Dallas Cowboys"]
> process.extract("new york jets", choices, limit=2)
  [('New York Jets', 100), ('New York Giants', 78)]
> process.extractOne("cowboys", choices)
  ("Dallas Cowboys", 90)
```

Answer (score 0):

[maybe this might help?](http://docs.python.org/2/library/difflib.html) It's a python diff library.

you can compute diffs between each string, if the two strings are highly similar, then you could probably (note probably) assume that since they have a lot in common, they could be the same company.

Comment: I have company names of One million ..I need to process this for all @ a time...in this case International business machines and IBM wont get much similiarity....i am thinking of approach which could solve this one also ...